# Generating Spring WS Client from RPC/encoded WSDL with ease?

Tags: java, wsdl, axis, rpc, spring-ws

Greetings everyone,

*Prior to my specific question, I'd like to mention that I am not looking for a step by step solution but for a possible YES or NO whether or not I will be able to achieve my goal with what I'm planning.*

**What I've got:**

A **wsdl** that was autogenerated by Axis 1.3 an that is RPC/encoded. - I dont have any influence on the Webservice per se.

**What I try to achieve:**

Generating a Spring WS Client from that wsdl.

**What I "know"**:

- RPC/encoded WSDLs are deprecated and not "supported" by Spring WS
- Spring WS can deliver any valid XML
- I have to get the schema from the WSDL - > .xsd
- I'm doomed.

**What I'm not sure of:**

- is the .xsd enough or do I need to generate/write an .xjb to generate the Classes?

**The Question:**

Is it possible for me to get the .xsd from the RPC/encoded WSDL and generate my Java Classes for the Spring WS Client without too much "hacking around"? Or should I just go along with developing cruel Axis 1.3 generated Classes with all their miseries?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you have any luck? I need to generate Java classes from an ancient WSDL file produced by Mantis Bug tracker and I can't use Axis1 because it does not work properly in OSGI. Axis2 and CXF failed because they didn't support rpc/encoded. what's left?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like Axis 1.3, JAX-RPC is a slightly easier to use alternative.